# Simple database + script in unix systems — best solution for concurrent invocations

Tags: database, unix, concurrency, scripting

In a Unix system, I want to create a SCRIPT that makes use of a very simple “database” with a singe table with three columns: [NAME, MAX, COUNT].
NAME: STRING is the key.
MAX: INTEGER is the maximum value for COUNT.
COUNT: INTEGER starts with zero and will be incremented by the script.

The SCRIPT is called with arg NAME. If COUNT == MAX the script will terminate immediately with exit code 1, otherwise it will increment the corresponding COUNT up to (and including) MAX and terminate with exit code 0.

**Important:** there will be multiple concurrent innovations of SCRIPT, but all concurrent invocations will have different arguments (different keys).

There are no limitations on the language/system used to implemente the script and the database.

Please advise on the best/easiest solution!

Comment: The original book 'The Awk Programming Language' (Aho, Kernigham, Weinberg) describes simple data processing projects as you describe. Also the first chapter ends with a list of ~15 one-liners showing the power of awk. While dated compared to the GNU Awk book (Robbins), the older book covers a lot of interesting applications . But  managing the files for such a system, especially given your concurrency requirements will add to the complexity of your project significantly. Of course without proper training/understanding you can muck a database tool too ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Was looking at an `awk` issue on another Q here and was reminded that the Aho,et.al. book has a tool called `qawk` (query awk), which could be what you're looking for. Search the web for that, but recall your use case sounds more complex than what is illustrated in the book and be prepared to handle managing the file/fileSystem on your own. You can find the actual code for qawk in https://9p.io/cm/cs/who/bwk/awkcode.txt, dnld the file, then `grep qawk awkcode.txt`. Without the book to explain, it may be confusing. Good luck.!

Comment: And finally, if you can't get your hands on the orig AWK book, here is a link to a very useful set of simple examples that can get you started [A Handful of Helpful One-Liners - in awk](https://jetlib.com/unix_tips/awktips.html) . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, I wonder if awk replaces strings 'in place' (i.e., in the same file) without creating/copying/renaming another one?  
I'll still give it a look… thanks for the suggestion(s).

Comment: New versions of `gawk` have an `--inline` argument that saves data without the need for `awk '{prog}' file > tmpFile && mv tmpFile file` dance (but it is doing that in the background for you). (I may not have the exact arg name there, as I'm just taking a quick look at S.O. this evening, so check your `man awk`). Good luck.

Comment: `gawk --inline` won't work for me because it won't handle concurrent updates.
I'll check the SQLite approach.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use just about any RDBMS for this. You just call

```
update mytable set mycount = mycount + 1 where name = :nameparam and mycount < mymax;
```

The DBMS will return the number of rows affected, which is either 0 or 1.

(I'm calling the columns mycount and mymax, because count and max are reserved words in SQL.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  But I was wondering if there was a simple(er) solution without making use of a full-bodied DB.

Comment: Just use a lightweight DBMS like SQLite. Install it, create the table, create that one script. Here is a link that may get you started: https://bigcode.wordpress.com/2016/05/10/sqlite-bash-script-tutorial-on-ubuntu-linux/ (As to concurrency: One script will write at a time and lock the table, the others wait for it to finish and then do their update. A database index on name will help finding the updating row quickly in case there are many.)